# Silverlight web app Unhandled exception code 4004

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to design a **Silverlight Application that accesses a SQL database through a WCF service**.  Operations that take place in the web app are fine, but as soon as I try to access data through the database I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception ('Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application)
Code: 4004
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.
```

It then gives me a list of debuggers to choose from, but upon choosing one it tells me its `"Unable to attach to the crashing process. A debugger is already attached."`

I'm fairly new to this and haven't been able to find much conclusive advise elsewhere.  Any input or similar experience to share is appreciated (:  Also I'm not sure what else would be helpful to solve this problem, so let me know if there's some other piece of info I should provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is saying that the code is failing and the exception generated hasn't been handled.

---

So I recommend that you put in a `try` `catch` around the location where you call the webservice for data and simply display a message box with the exception text. And/or put a breakpoint in the location of where the silverlight application calls the webservice. Run the debugger. See what value comes back and how its handled.

---

Hence I whole-heartedly recommend that you put in try catches in your code and to **also** handle any future failures and report them appropriately; for this won't be the only exception your code will generate.

Comment: Thanks.  Adding the try catch worked to handle the exception, but I haven't been able to debug the wcf service because the breakpoint is giving me a "Breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols loaded for this document." error which I haven't been able to resolve. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KyleBreton Do you build the service in the same solution as the project? If so on could Step-Into the service depending on how its setup to run. Or start the service in the debugger with your needed breakpoint and then just run the Silverlight app outside of the debugger to call the service.

Comment: Yeah I figured out how to set it up to step into the service.  Thanks for your help!